# Getting No Access-Control-Allow-Origin cors error but the header is set and works fine in local environment but will not work live on render.com

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, render.com

Summary: I am using cors npm on nodejs backend and am able ON LOCAL MACHINE to successfully make requests from frontend on a port separate from backend. IN PRODUCTION I get a cors error saying no Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set. My sever.js file included at the end. Thanks!

Full explanation:

I have an app with a separate backend folder and frontend folder. The backend is built with nodejs. The frontend is reactjs and is making axios calls successfully from localhost:3000 to the backend server running on localhost:5000. When I inspect element in chrome browser while running locally it shows the header for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin being successfully "set" by the backend.

In production on new render.com site i have the frontend on a static render.com app and the backend on render.com web service app. The both work / run fine as separate apps but when the frontend goes to make any api calls to the backend it gets the No Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. When i check the chrome inspect under network headers it doesn't show the Access-Control-Allow-Origin being set like it did in the local environment.

I have tried rebuilding front and back to clear cache but without success. I have set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to just "*" just to get it to show up on the live environment without success. I have tried several varieties of the following without success:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Also:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "UPDATE", "PUT"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

None of these methods have worked. I made sure this is all before routes are being run as well in the server.js file as "high up" as i could put them in that file.

Screenshot of local headers on chrome inspect tool:
[image]

production headers:
[image]

Here is my server.js file that is attempting to set the headers and setup cors npm package. I left in several of the commented out tests just to show some of the things I have tested. The current test that is in there is my attempt to have the cors npm package set the headers:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const request = require('request')
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBSession = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//   next();
// });

// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
//   next();
// });

// app.get('/*',function(req,res,next){
//   res.header('X-XSS-Protection' , 0 );
//   next(); // http://expressjs.com/guide.html#passing-route control
// });

// app.use(cors())

//actual connection to the mongodb server
const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

const store = new MongoDBSession({
  uri: uri,
  collection: 'mySessions',
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

let allowUrls = "*"

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: allowUrls,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "UPDATE", "PUT"],
    credentials: true,
    // allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-Requested-With', 'device-remember-token', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Origin', 'Accept']
  })
);


// app.use(cors())
// app.options('*', cors());
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
//   next();
// });

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})); //Post Body Parser

app.use(
  session({
    key: "userId",
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      expires: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    },
    store: store,
  })
);

// app.use(cors());
// app.use(cors({
//   origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
//   methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
//   credentials: true
// }));

const example = require('./routes/example');
//... lots more routes here

app.use('/example', example);
//... more here

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('hit get request for /: ', res)
  res.sendStatus(200)
})

const port = !process.env.NODE_ENV ? 5000 : process.env.PORT;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port} process.env.NODE_ENV = ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
});
```

Comment: Don't write your own CORS middleware, just use the standard `cors()` one

Comment: Are you sure your front-end is sending requests to the correct URL? Should be something like `https://your-app.onrender.com/`

Comment: Good question. I should have included in description but yes I have made sure I am sending the requests to the correct backend url. Just that one origin header I can’t get to set for some reason @Phil

Comment: The browser sets the `Origin` header automatically. Have you tested the service URLs with `curl` or Postman? Eg `curl -v -H "Origin: https://your-frontend.onrender.com" "https://your-web-service.onrender.com"` That should show you the response headers

Comment: yes i have tested with postman and I have also looked at the headers in the network tab of chrome inspect tool. that is where i can see on my local environment it sets the header but on the live web service app it isn't setting the header. ill add image/screenshots of those headers

Comment: So when you say you tested with Postman, do you see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response? You may need to add an `Origin` request header. Could you also please [edit] your question to make it clear which CORS middleware you're using and how. FYI, I would start with the simplest version... `app.use(cors())`

Comment: Seems odd that the only CORS header in the response is `access-control-allow-credentials`

Comment: Yes I have and am using `app.use(cors()) ` and it does auto set origin To “*” if I understood the npm documentation correctly but I have also attempted to do res.header like everyone else suggests and that didn’t change anything. Just works in local not in live

Comment: There are still two CORS middlewares mentioned in your question; your manual one using `res.header()` and the `cors()` one. You should not have both. Please [edit] your question to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means including enough server-side code to replicate request handling and enough client-side code to replicate request sending

Comment: Thanks Phil. I have included my server.js file in there. Hopefully that's minimal enough. But yes, I have tested both the "manual" res.header setting before app.use(cors()) as well as tested both of them by themselves without any change. Currently I have just cors running and it should be setting the headers in that "origins" section of the code but let me know what i'm missing

Comment: 1) You should register the `cors()` middleware first so errors in other middlewares don't break CORS handling. 2) Why use `bodyParser.urlencoded()` when you already have `express.urlencoded()`? 3) You can't use `credentials` with `*` origins. Are you actually using cross-site cookies? 4) Where is your client-side code that makes requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. I ditched cors npm and just use res.header method since my main issues was that I could figure out how to get cors to set the origin header:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://gamebrag.onrender.com', 'https://gamebrag.onrender.com'];
      const origin = req.headers.origin;
      if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
           res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
      }
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-credentials", true);
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, UPDATE");
      next();
    });
```

Made sure it was as high up as possible but after `const app = express();`

I am guessing I was accidentally including `app.use(cors())` with the res.headers which also messed things up. Render.com was also having issues with their free web services in the oregon/west usa area which I resolved by creating a new free web service in usa east.

Comment: All you literally needed was `app.use(cors({ origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://gamebrag.onrender.com', 'https://gamebrag.onrender.com'], credentials: true }))`. Your manual version fails to handle pre-flight `OPTIONS` requests properly

Comment: I am not having any pre-flight errors but will take a look if it comes in the future. thanks Phil

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my backend on Render. I was editing the "Content-Length" response header to convey the file size to my frontend for download progress.

```js
    res.set("Content-Length", `${fileSize}`); //bad. causes cors issue
```

The moment I removed this line, the cors policy error went away.
I got around this by instead using a custom header and exposing it using "Access-Control-Expose-Headers". I'm new so I'm not sure if this is bad practice.

```js
    res.set({ "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "X-File-Size" });
    res.set("X-File-Size", `${fileSize}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

If there's no restrictions about dependencies in your project, you might try Cors https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Yes I am using cors. See the second example block of code in my question. Even if I do app.use and set headers I still have to have cors used as well. Again, works fine in local but not in production/live on render.com

Comment: Im sorry but you did not have the code examples by the time I try to answer this question, that's why I went straight to the package